# force overflow without fixed width

Tags: html, css

I'm creating an image scroller (or carousel I think it may be called) where basically I have a horizontal element, that has a horizontally scrolling child element. The problem is, I want the parent to be 100% width, while I want the child to overflow but I want its width to be dynamic not fixed so that I can add as many elements inside as I want without specifying a fixed width.

Is this possible? Here's an example of what I'm working on right now, but currently, the scrollable element that overflows has a fixed width so I can allow it to overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/xhhmtmgn/132/

```
<div class='parent'> width here is 100%
  <div class='horizontal-scroll'> width here is anything, depends on how many items are inside
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
    <div class='item'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the high-level basic idea of what the html is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `white-space` and drop `float` for `inline-block` https://jsfiddle.net/xhhmtmgn/133/ then `width` and `absolute` positionning are not needed anymore.